# How can I execute commands from PHP?

Tags: php

I mean if somebody clicks on a button then it runs a command and create a file. I want it on Windows Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For executing commands in php you can use

### [**exec()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

> exec — Execute an external program

### **[system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)**

> system — Execute an external program and display the output

### **[passthru()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)**

> passthru — Execute an external program and display raw output

There working is different based on how they return the data.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `exec` keyword to execute command on linux or windows but
if you use on window server put **fullpath** of **php.exe** and **script.php**
as example

```
exec("d:/path/php/executable/php.exe d:/wamp/www/program/defender/tester.php", $myout);

print_r($myout);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use you can use such as [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php), [``](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php), [exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), [proc_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php), [passthru()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)

```
$command = 'ping -c 3 stackoverflow.com';

//shell_exec()
shell_exec($command);

//system()
system($command);

//``
`$command`;

//exec()
exec($command);

//proc_open()
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("file", "/tmp/error-output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);
$process = proc_open($command, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

//passthru()
passthru($command);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a button or a form on the client, then you have to implement logic, so that a request is sent to your server after pressing the button.

Then on the server side, you have to execute your code:

e.g.

```
<?php
  echo shell_exec('cmd /?h > randomFile.txt');
```

Comment: it this shell_exec working on windows server or only on linux?

Comment: Works also on windows